# Появляется огромная белая полоса с Bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

Привет!Я начал делать адаптив для сайта и заметил что начала появлятся огромная белая полоса справа(видно на скриншоте).С чем это связано и как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пока что все более менее,но если проскролить вправо то...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import "vars"
@import "fonts"
@import "libs"

ul
    list-style: none

.Companyname
    font-family: $PoiretOne
    color: $white
    font-size: 30px
    margin-top: 74px
    padding-left: 174px
    margin-bottom: 0px
    span:last-child
        color: #C9C9C6
        font-size: 28px 

.first-block
    background-color: $bg-gray
.Top-menu
    display: flex
    margin-top: 75px
    margin-bottom: 0px
    li
        margin-left: 15px
        a
            color: $white
            font-size: 13px
            font-family: $MontserratRegular
            text-decoration: none
            text-transform: uppercase
            &::after
                content: ''
                width: 100%
                height: 2px
                display: block
                background-color: $white
                transform: scale(0)
                transition: all 0.2s 
            &:hover
                    &::after
                        transform: scale(1)
.BigGrayText
    color: $white
    font-size: 50px
    margin-left: 172px
    margin-top: 196px
    font-family: $CabinRegular
    width: 640px
.first-block-2
    background-color: $bg-gray
    button
        background-color: $green
        width: 224px
        height: 56px
        outline: none
        border: none
        color: $white
        text-transform: uppercase
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 13px
        border-radius: 5px 
        margin-top: 60px
.SmallGrayText
    font-size: 15px
    width: 574px
    margin-left: 174px
    font-family: $LatoLight 
    color: $white
    line-height: 32px
    margin-bottom: 272px
.second-block
    background-color: $white
    margin-bottom: 100px
    &-bigtext
        font-family: $CabinRegular
        font-size: 48px
        width: 100%
        color: $very-dark
        text-align: center
        margin-top: 128px
.second-block-2
    margin-left: 176px
    margin-right: 176px
    margin-bottom: 150px
    &-icon
        font-size: 30px
        color: $white
        width: 65px
        height: 65px
        text-align: center
        background-color: $green
        border-radius: 50%
        line-height: 62px
        transform: translateY(-30px)
    &-iconcontainer
        display: flex
        justify-content: center
        width: 100%
    &-main
        display: flex
        justify-content: center
        flex-direction: column
        flex-wrap: wrap
        width: 280px
        border: 1px solid #f2f2f2
    &-bigtext
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 18px
        color: $very-dark
        text-align: center
        text-transform: uppercase
    &-smalltext
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        font-size: 16px
        text-align: center
.third-block
    background-color: $gray
    &-bigtext
        font-family: $CabinRegular
        color: $very-dark
        font-size: 48px
        margin-bottom: 40px
        width: 510px
        margin-top: 128px
    &-text
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        color: $text-gray
        font-size: 16px
        margin-bottom: 20px
        width: 510px
    &-button
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 15px
        text-transform: uppercase
        color: $very-dark
        border: 1px solid $very-dark
        border-radius: 5px
        padding: 15px
        width: 232px
        text-align: center
        margin-bottom: 130px
        &:hover
            color: $green
            border: 1px solid $green
            transition: all 0.2s
.ClientsBigText
    font-family: $CabinRegular
    font-size: 48px
    color: $very-dark
    text-align: center
    width: 100%
    margin-top: 128px
.ClientMain
    width: 437px
.ClientText
    font-family: $LatoRegular
    font-size: 16px
    color: $text-gray
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2
    padding: 15px
.block__hint
    position: relative
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2
    background: $white
.block__hint::after
    display: block
    content: ""
    position: absolute
    height: 15px
    width: 15px
    background: $white
    border-left: 2px solid #f2f2f2
    border-top: 2px solid #f2f2f2
    bottom: -10px
    right: 20px
    transform: rotate(-135deg)
.ClientPerson
    text-align: right
    float: left
    width: 83%
    span:first-child
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 15px
        color: $very-dark
    span:last-child
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        font-size: 13px
        color: #666666
.ClientImage
    border-radius: 50%
    margin-left: 15px
    width: 58px
    height: 58px
.fourth-bloc
     background-color: #353535
.ExpMain
    display: flex
    justify-content: flex-end
.Exp
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    &-BigText
        font-family: $CabinRegular
        font-size: 48px
        color: $white
        width: 465px
        margin-top: 130px
    &-Text
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        font-size: 15px
        color: $white
        width: 465px
    &-Button
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 15px
        border: 2px solid $white
        border-radius: 5px
        padding: 18px
        width: 234px
        margin-top: 35px
        margin-bottom: 150px
        &:hover
            color: $green
            transition: all 0.2s
            border: 2px solid $green
        span
            padding: 20px 25px 20px 25px
            a
                color: $white
                text-transform: uppercase
                text-decoration: none
.SkillsMain
    margin-left: 20px
.Skills
    &-text
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        font-size: 15px
        color: $white
.Progress
    position: relative
    width: 490px
    height: 20px
    background-color: $white
.bar
    position: absolute
    width: 1%
    height: 100%
    background-color: $green
    &::after
        display: block
        content: ""
        position: absolute
        height: 10px
        width: 10px
        background: #353535
        border-left: 2px solid $very-dark
        border-top: 2px solid $very-dark
        bottom: 25px
        right: 0px
        transform: rotate(-135deg)
.BlogBigText
    font-family: $CabinRegular
    font-size: 48px
    color: $very-dark
    width: 100%
    text-align: center
    margin-top: 120px
    margin-bottom: 60px
.MainBlog
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    margin-bottom: 114px
.Blog
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: center
    img
        width: 310px
        height: 195px
        margin-bottom: 15px
    &-bigtext
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 18px
        color: $very-dark
        margin-left: 15px
    &-graytext
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        font-size: 14px
        color: #999999
        margin-left: 15px
        span
            span
                padding-left: 5px
                padding-right: 5px
        span:last-child
            padding-left: 10px
    &-text
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        font-size: 16px
        color: $text-gray
        margin-left: 15px
.ReadyRow
    background-color: $green
    height: 175px
.ReadyMain
    margin-top: 30px
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    p:first-child
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 24px
        color: $white
        padding-left: 15px
    p:last-child
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        font-size: 16px
        color: $white
        padding-left: 15px
.Readybtn
    display: flex
    justify-content: flex-start
.Ready-Button
    font-family: $LatoBold
    font-size: 16px
    color: $white
    text-transform: uppercase
    border: 2px solid $white
    padding: 10px
    border-radius: 5px
    margin-top: 30px
    a
        color: $white
        text-decoration: none
        padding: 15px
.FooterRow
    background-color: #232323
.Companynamefooter
    font-family: $PoiretOne
    color: $white
    font-size: 30px
    span:last-child
        color: #C9C9C6
        font-size: 28px 
.FooterInfo
    margin-bottom: 70px
    margin-top: 50px
    p:first-child
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 15px
        color: $white
        text-transform: uppercase
    p:last-child
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        font-size: 14px
        color: $white
    &-Adress
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        font-size: 14px
        color: $white

@media (max-width: 1053px)
    .Companyname
        padding-left: 50px
@media (max-width: 770px)
    .Top-menu
        margin-top: 30px
        li
            margin-left: 40px
@media (max-width: 510px)
    .Top-menu
        display: none









@import "media" // Always at the end
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <base href="/">

 <title>CompanyName</title>
 <meta name="description" content="">

 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

 <!-- Template Basic Images Start -->
 <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/image.jpg">
 <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/favicon/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
 <!-- Template Basic Images End -->

 <!-- Custom Browsers Color Start -->
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#FFF">
 <!-- Custom Browsers Color End -->
 <script defer src="libs/fontawesome-free-5.0.8/svg-with-js/js/fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css">

</head>

<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row first-block align-items-center ">
   <p class="Companyname col-xl-7 col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
    <span>company</span>
    <span>name</span>
   </p>
   <ul class="col-xl-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 Top-menu">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="row first-block-2">
   <p class="BigGrayText">
    We’re here to create your online presense and style
   </p>
   <p class="SmallGrayText">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse mattis orci dapibus risus dignissim, viverra pellentesque
    arcu ullamcorper. Mauris a tincidunt lectus. Proin nec venenatis quam.
    <br>
    <button>start today with us</button>
   </p>

  </div>
  <div class="row second-block">
   <p class="second-block-bigtext">Features you’ll love</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row  second-block-2">
   <div class="col-4">
    <div class="second-block-2-main">
     <div class="second-block-2-iconcontainer">
      <p class="second-block-2-icon">
       <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      </p>
     </div>
     <p class="second-block-2-bigtext">Personal touch</p>
     <p class="second-block-2-smalltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra
      lorem.
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
    <div class="second-block-2-main">
     <div class="second-block-2-iconcontainer">
      <p class="second-block-2-icon">
       <i class="fas fa-flag"></i>
      </p>
     </div>
     <p class="second-block-2-bigtext">Unique solutions</p>
     <p class="second-block-2-smalltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra
      lorem.
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
    <div class="second-block-2-main">
     <div class="second-block-2-iconcontainer">
      <p class="second-block-2-icon">
       <i class="fas fa-paint-brush"></i>
      </p>
     </div>
     <p class="second-block-2-bigtext">Help in promotion</p>
     <p class="second-block-2-smalltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra
      lorem.
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-end third-block">
   <div class="col-6">
    <p class="third-block-bigtext">Our Short Story</p>
    <p class="third-block-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra lorem.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra
     lorem. .
    </p>
    <br>
    <p class="third-block-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra lorem.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra
     lorem.

    </p>
    <br>
    <p class="third-block-button">More about our team</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <p class="ClientsBigText">Our Clients Says</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-5">
    <div class="ClientMain">
     <p class="ClientText block__hint">
      Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus
      ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
     </p>
     <p class="ClientPerson">
      <span>Joe Doe</span>
      <br>
      <span>Creative Deirector at Gmoogle.com</span>
     </p>
     <img class="ClientImage" src="img/photo-person.png" alt="ClientPhoto">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-5">
    <div class="ClientMain">
     <p class="ClientText block__hint">
      Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus
      ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
     </p>
     <p class="ClientPerson">
      <span>Joe Doe</span>
      <br>
      <span>Creative Deirector at Gmoogle.com</span>
     </p>
     <img class="ClientImage" src="img/photo-person.png" alt="ClientPhoto">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-5">
    <div class="ClientMain">
     <p class="ClientText block__hint">
      Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus
      ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
     </p>
     <p class="ClientPerson">
      <span>Joe Doe</span>
      <br>
      <span>Creative Deirector at Gmoogle.com</span>
     </p>
     <img class="ClientImage" src="img/photo-person.png" alt="ClientPhoto">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-5">
    <div class="ClientMain">
     <p class="ClientText block__hint">
      Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus
      ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
     </p>
     <p class="ClientPerson">
      <span>Joe Doe</span>
      <br>
      <span>Creative Deirector at Gmoogle.com</span>
     </p>
     <img class="ClientImage" src="img/photo-person.png" alt="ClientPhoto">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row fourth-bloc">
   <div class="col">
    <div class="ExpMain">
     <div class="Exp">
      <p class="Exp-BigText">Our Experience</p>
      <p class="Exp-Text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra
       lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id,
       pharetra lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor
       id, pharetra lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur
       tortor id, pharetra lorem.
      </p>
      <p class="Exp-Button">
       <span>
        <a href="#">View case studies</a>
       </span>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
    <div class="SkillsMain">
     <div class="Skills">
      <p class="Exp-BigText">Skills</p>
      <p class="Skills-text">C++ development</p>
      <div class="Progress" id="Progress1" onscroll="move(95)">
       <div class="bar" id="bar1">

       </div>
      </div>
      <p class="Skills-text">.Net</p>
      <div class="Progress" id="Progress2" onscroll="move2(75)">
       <div class="bar" id="bar2">

       </div>
      </div>
      <p class="Skills-text">HTML5</p>
      <div class="Progress" id="Progress3" onscroll="move(85)">
       <div class="bar" id="bar3">

       </div>
      </div>
      <p class="Skills-text">jQuery</p>
      <div class="Progress" id="Progress4" onscroll="move(90)">
       <div class="bar" id="bar4">

       </div>
      </div>
      <p class="Skills-text">Angular</p>
      <div class="Progress" id="Progress5" onscroll="move(70)">
       <div class="bar" id="bar5">

       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <p class="BlogBigText">From the Blog</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-3">
    <div class="MainBlog">
     <div class="Blog">
      <img src="img/BlogImage.png" alt="BlogImage">
      <p class="Blog-bigtext">Cache Invalidation Strategies With Varnish Cache</p>
      <p class="Blog-graytext">
       <span><span><i class="far fa-calendar"></span></i>March 4, 2014</span>
       <span><span><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></span>2 comments</span>
      </p>
      <p class="Blog-text">Shortly thereafter, I was working with RetailMeNot, tasked with designing its iOS and Android app tutorial. The product
       team wanted to make sure hat users were clear about the value</p>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
    <div class="MainBlog">
     <div class="Blog">
      <img src="img/BlogImage.png" alt="BlogImage">
      <p class="Blog-bigtext">Cache Invalidation Strategies With Varnish Cache</p>
      <p class="Blog-graytext">
       <span><span><i class="far fa-calendar"></span></i>March 4, 2014</span>
       <span><span><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></span>2 comments</span>
      </p>
      <p class="Blog-text">Shortly thereafter, I was working with RetailMeNot, tasked with designing its iOS and Android app tutorial. The product
       team wanted to make sure hat users were clear about the value</p>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
    <div class="MainBlog">
     <div class="Blog">
      <img src="img/BlogImage.png" alt="BlogImage">
      <p class="Blog-bigtext">Cache Invalidation Strategies With Varnish Cache</p>
      <p class="Blog-graytext">
       <span><span><i class="far fa-calendar"></span></i>March 4, 2014</span>
       <span><span><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></span>2 comments</span>
      </p>
      <p class="Blog-text">Shortly thereafter, I was working with RetailMeNot, tasked with designing its iOS and Android app tutorial. The product
       team wanted to make sure hat users were clear about the value</p>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ReadyRow align-items-center justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-8">
    <div class="ReadyMain">
     <p>Are you ready to go?</p>
     <p>Here the call to action area. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and click to the button</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
    <div class="Readybtn"><p class="Ready-Button"><a href="#">Start your project</a></p></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-around FooterRow">
   <div class="col-2">
    <p class="Companynamefooter">
     <span>company</span>
     <span>name</span>
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
    <div class="FooterInfoMain">
     <div class="FooterInfo">
      <p>new york</p>
      <p class="FooterInfo-Adress">Address goes here in a one or two 
       lines, maybe lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>
       <span>+44 800 800 90</span><span>info@domen.com</span> 
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-2">
    <div class="FooterInfoMain">
     <div class="FooterInfo">
      <p>london</p>
      <p class="FooterInfo-Adress">Address goes here in a one or two 
       lines, maybe lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>
       <span>+44 800 800 90</span><span>info@domen.com</span> 
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
     <div class="FooterInfoMain">
      <div class="FooterInfo">
       <p>madrid</p>
       <p class="FooterInfo-Adress">Address goes here in a one or two 
        lines, maybe lorem ipsum</p>
       <p>
        <span>+44 800 800 90</span><span>info@domen.com</span> 
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 <script src="js/scripts.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Извините что скинул SASS,CSS минифицируется.

Comment: Когда Вы в редакторе кода в браузере пробегаете по блокам div, вы видите подсветку на рабочей странице. 
Проверьте какой div вызвал смещение (может текст вылез, может стиль слетел, может тег не закрыт), и когда нашли блок который вызывает смещение (имеет размер шире чем нужно) там и копайте.

Comment: В "Инструментах разработчика" удаляйте поочередно блоки, пока не найдете нужный, создающий прокрутку. Часто это бывают сокрытые, абсолютно позиционированные, элементы.

Comment: Спасибо,сейчас попробую.

Comment: Просмотрел блоки в браузере и заметил что мешал `div`, я добавил ему класс `col-lg-7` и он после `992px` начинает занимать 100% рабочей области и `justify-content-end` не работает.Добавил скрин в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас много элементов в фиксированной шириной, к примеру

> width: 510px, width: 437px

проверьте, может именно они и не помещаются в контейнер.

Второй вариант такой - задаете всем элементам рамку и смотрите какой элемент выходит за контейнер

```
*{
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: + не плохой наглядный способ для поиска, обычно просто ищу наведением через инспектор,  правда тогда еще бы добавила бордер на все before/after

Comment: рад что смог помочь